# How to post on angularjs in https

Tags: angularjs, ssl, https, iis-express, visual-studio-cordova

here is my angularjs request whenever I submit a request it returns error and no delay.

```
   var req = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost:44300/authentication/login',
            data: { UserID: Username, Password: Password },
            dataType: "json"
        });

        req.success(
            function (result) {
                 alert('success');
            });
        req.error(function (result) {
                 alert('something went wrong');
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it `404` error? then yes it should be, because your pointing to `localhost`, if you setup `https` it should work as normal

Comment: the web api is setup on the same machine what im using I've tried the http local url and its working but when I use the SSL it throws an error  '[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats how I do and it always works fine

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var url = 'your url';
$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: {}
      })
      .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(msg);                        
      });

      return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I used the code if I access the http url its OK but then if I access the ssl url https it returns 500

Comment: and what's happening when you open url in a browser ??